How to scroll with Pivot using just Column Composable?
Trying to create a view for TV devices using Jetpack Compose that consists of a main Column which contains mutiple rows.
Is there some way to scroll through a Column composable whilst also maintaining a pivot?
Such that all items always come to the top of the screen when scrolled to.
I understand this may be a unconventional request and I can just use TvLazyColumn for this impementation. But I want everything to be loaded by the time I start scrolling. Using TvLazyColumn is giving me some degree of scrolling lag which I'm trying to avoid. I can make do with a longer initial loading time but the scrolling should be smooth.
